# Swift - MPMusicPlayer playback progress as UISlider

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uislider, mpmusicplayercontroller

I'm having problem animate UISlider as a MPMusicPlayer playback progress. I've seen many post accomplishing this on obj-c and AVAudioPlayer.

I've tried this:

```
func startTimer(){
    if timer == nil {
        timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1.0, target: self, selector: Selector("update:"), userInfo: nil,repeats: true)
        timer.fire()
    }
}

func stopTimer(){
    timer.invalidate()

}


func update(timer: NSTimer){
     if myMusicPlayer?.playbackState == MPMusicPlaybackState.Playing{
        return
    }

    var minute_ = abs(Int((myMusicPlayer!.currentPlaybackTime / 60) % 60))
    var second_ = abs(Int(myMusicPlayer!.currentPlaybackTime  % 60))

    var minute = minute_ > 9 ? "\(minute_)" : "0\(minute_)"
    var second = second_ > 9 ? "\(second_)" : "0\(second_)"

    progressTimerLabel.text  = "\(minute):\(second)"
    progressBar.value = CFloat(myMusicPlayer!.currentPlaybackTime)

}
```

ProgressBar is my UISlider.

I called startTimer() when I play the audio, but it still not animate at all. What can I do so it animate the UISlider?

Comment: does your control reach `progressBar.value = CFloat(myMusicPlayer!.currentPlaybackTime)` this line? verify it by adding a breakpoint at the return statement and one at progressBar.value line

Comment: I've tried println(myMusicPlayer!.currentPlaybackTime) and it only appears once. I think it should appears many time as the timer running.

Comment: shouldn't you be returning if the state is != `Playing`?

Comment: I suspect return statement is the culprit. I agree with @konrad.bajtyngier for return statement.

Comment: yes the problem is that return :D , I put the code on the if myMusicPlayer?.playbackState == MPMusicPlaybackState.Playing then worked fine